# How to monitor log files via Nagios

Tags: linux, nagios

Is it possible that i can monitor . kernel log messages , apache error logs , mail log messages via nagios.

I have three linux servers and i want that on every server there should be something so that i can see all log files from one locations

I am new to nagios so i don't know

Comment: The first thing you need to do is define exactly what you mean by "monitor" log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole category of Log Monitoring plugins over on the [Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Log-Files). The [check_logfiles](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Log-Files/check_logfiles/details) plugin looks promising. You should know, though, that there's no "magic" log monitoring plugin. You need to be able to tell the plugin what you're looking for (in the form of a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)) so that it can alert you when it finds a match.

Comment: Is nagios only monitors for some expression or is it possible with nagios that , when i click on log file , it then opens the current contents of that file. i just want to view the contents from one location

Comment: Oh, just viewing log files is really outside of what Nagios does. For that, you should first get all of your servers sending their logs to a central syslog server. Then from there, give php-syslog-ng a try: http://code.google.com/p/php-syslog-ng/

Answer (score 2):

As was already pointed out, to monitor log files, you have to identify what it is you want.

Based on what I gather from your post, you want to monitor and alert on log files, and you also want to be able to view the content of the logs.

I'm going to presume when you say "view", you actually mean that when a problem is identified in a monitored log, you want the alert to show the offending lines or entries that triggered the alert.

If you had something else in mind when you said "view", you should know, it is completely inefficient to "monitor" logs the way you described.  "viewing" isn't going to provide an efficient method of accomplishing what you want.  You can't possibly expect to visually monitor several logs on different hosts, and catch an issue.

To monitor several logs on different hosts the right way, from one central location, its either you use [splunk](http://www.splunk.com), [logrobot](http://www.logrobot.com), or the aforementioned check_logfiles (haven't really used this one but it may be worth checking out).